# Is it possible to stack more Partial Classes in the same place with the SomeForm.Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#

). I would love to be able to do that. I got a rather large class for a Form in my Visual Studio 2008 project (>1000 lines) so I broke it into 2 more partial classes. You know how Visual Studio hooks the .Designer.cs file under the master code file?

Well, since my form is called "frmMain", I tried renaming my classes into frmMain.SomeMethods.cs and frmMain.SomeOtherMethods.cs. Unfortunately, I can't find how to hook them under frmMain.cs, like frmMain.Designer.cs and frmMain.resx ::- (.

Probably not possible, but I thought I'd ask the experts first ;;- ).

Thank you.

And a Happy New Year to everybody!!! ::- D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can definitely do it - it's just a matter of editing the project file.

My [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) project does this - for example:

```
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExtTest.cs" />
<Compile Include="Linq\Extensions\DataProducerExtTest.Conversion.cs">
  <DependentUpon>DataProducerExtTest.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
...
```

It's a shame you have to edit it by hand to get the effect, but it can work very well.

Comment: Haha. Great stuff! Just a matter of replacing "<SubType>Form</SubType>" with "<DependentUpon>frmMain.cs</DependentUpon>". Thank you very much Jon! ::- ). Now if only they could add some stuff to better control this in VS 2010. Also annoying that on double click it opens an empty Designer.